# How to deploy workload to GCP Kubernetes Programatically?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have achieved vast amount of automation in terms of creating projects, creating kubernetes engine and other IaaS elements, by using GCP APIs from Python GCP Client.

But I am not very positive on deploying docker container workloads to the provisioned cluster. The GCP documents point to kubectl apply -f config.yaml, but this entails using command line tools by first switching to project etc...

This is exactly what I am trying to get away from. Is there a google API that lets us accomplish this?

And no, I do not want third party deployment automation tools for various reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Kubernetes client library to deploy workload programatically.

Here is some client for kubernetes:

1. Go client: [client-go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go)
2. Java client: [kubernetes-client/java](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java)
3. Python client: [kubernetes-client/python](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python)